# Create object - product with name and price - best practice C#

Tags: c#, object

The program should create a car which can have many parts and be able to set a part which always has a corresponding price to it.

My current car and part classes:

```cs
public class Car
{
    public Car(string brand, string windshieldType, List<AdditionalCarParts> additionalCarParts) {
        Brand = brand;
        WindshieldType = windshieldType;
        AdditionalCarParts = additionalCarParts;
    }

    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string WindshieldType { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public List<AdditionalCarParts> AdditionalCarParts { get; set; }
}

public class AdditionalCarParts
{
    public AdditionalCarParts(PartData.PartNames part, int price) {
        Part = part;
        Price = price;
    }
    
    public PartData.PartNames Part { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

public class PartData
{
    public enum PartNames
    {
        EngineHeater,
        SteeringWheelHeater,
        HeadsUpDisplay,
        Turbo
    }
        
    public static int EngineHeaterPrice() => 3000;
    public static int SteeringWheelHeaterPrice() => 800;
    public static int HeadsUpDisplayPrice() => 1200;
    public static int TurboPrice() => 5000;
       
    }
}
```

How to add one part to list of parts in my car, and that part has a price on it, for example:
`var part = new AdditionalCarParts(PartData.PartNames.Turbo)` and an object is created with price of 5000 set on it.

Should there even be a list of parts, or are there any better practices for this?

Thanks.

Comment: One 'best practice' thing I can tell you right away is to not make the "Additional Car Part" and "part name" plural in their class name. Each one of them is only one part / one name, after all.

Comment: Oh, and you're using an enum to differentiate the _types_ of parts, not to set their name. So a much more logical name for that enum is `PartType`.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a class to hold the prices. I would use a data structure as a Dictionary to hold that info.

```
public class AdditionalCarParts
{
    public AdditionalCarParts(PartData.PartNames part, int price) {
        Part = part;
        //Price = price;
    }

    public enum PartNames
    {
        EngineHeater,
        SteeringWheelHeater,
        HeadsUpDisplay,
        Turbo
    }
    
    private Dictionary<PartNames, int> prices = new Dictionary<PartNames, int>() {
        { PartNames.EngineHeater, 3000 },
        { PartNames.SteeringWheelHeater, 800 },
        { PartNames.HeadsUpDisplay, 1200 },
        { PartNames.Turbo, 5000 },
        
    }; 
    public PartNames Part { get; set; }
    public int Price(PartNames name) => prices[name];
}
```

"How to add one part to list of parts in my car" -> I find that adding it to the list is fine. As the prices are already pre-defined you would not need to provide the price in the class constructor.

If prices can change, you can handle that with a `SetPrice` method to update the dictionary. I would do:

```
public void SetPrice(PartNames name, int price) {
    prices[name] = price;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to recommend.

Comment: Dictionary was the key! Thanks!

Comment: This will make the prices data get created as separate Dictionary in every object of the car part class you make, though, and SetPrice will only have any effect if you do it on an object of the actual part type you're changing. It seems better to make the prices static.